# Data structure padding

Tags: c++, data-structures

What is data structure padding in c++ and how do i check the number of bytes padded bytes?

```
class a { public: int x; int y; int z; };
```

Comment: I've read sizeof operator returns the size along with padded bytes so i was just wondering.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  If you are merely interested for curiosity's sake, the two answers below are reasonable.  You shouldn't be trying to find out about padding so you can write code that makes assumptions about it.  Such code might not be portable.

Answer (score 4):

Processors require that certain types of data have particular alignments.  For example, a processor might require that an `int` be on a 4-byte boundary.  So, for example, an `int` could start at memory location `0x4000` but it could not start at `0x4001`.  So if you defined a class:

```
class a
{
public:
    char c;
    int i;
};
```

the compiler would have to insert padding between `c` and `i` so that `i` could start on a 4-byte boundary.

Comment: meaning you wouldn't have any padding in your example if it is started on a byte boundary.  which it should be.

Comment: This answer is generally true for the overwhelming majority of processors / compilers you are likely to encounter.  Just don't rely on it being precisely true invariably.

Comment: "processors require" - sometimes true, other times it's not required (i.e. it won't SIGBUS or similar if unaligned) but does perform better.

Comment: Not completely correct. Most processors are byte addressable, therefore integers can start at any byte address. However, compilers will place an int on a 4/8 byte boundary because doing so increases system performance due to the way the CPU handles memory operations.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct A
{
    char c;
    int i;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;

    cout << "sizeof struct = " << sizeof(A) << endl;

    cout << "sizeof items  = " << sizeof(a.c) + sizeof(a.i) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

padding is done for performance reasons - see this article [Data Structure Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) for more info.

To see whether the compiler pads your data structure you could write a simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

class a {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl; // print the total size in bytes required per class instance

    a anInstance;
    std::cout << &anInstance.x << std::endl; // print the address of the x member
    std::cout << &anInstance.y << std::endl; // as above but for y
    std::cout << &anInstance.z << std::endl; // etc
}
```

I added the public declaration to avoid compiler errors - It will not affect the size or padding.

Edit: Running this on my macbook air gives the following output:
    12
    0x7fff5fbff650
    0x7fff5fbff654
    0x7fff5fbff658

This shows that on my machine the total size is 12 bytes, and each member is 4 bytes apart. The ints are 4 bytes each (which can be confirmed with sizeof(int)). There is no padding.

Try this with different members in your class, for example:

```
class b {
    public:
        char      w;
        char      x[6];
        int       y;
        long long z;
};
```

Comment: "padding is done for performance reasons"... sometimes, other times the CPU will actually SIGBUS or similar if asked to access non-aligned data.

Answer (score 0):

Lol just create 2 identical structs, make one of them packed
e.g.

```
struct foo {
  int  a;
  char b;
  int  c;
} 

struct bar {
  int  a;
  char b;
  int  c;
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

`sizeof(foo) - sizeof(bar)`
will give you the amount of padding. Or you could also calculate manually like Duck suggested.