# Modify core java libraries of Android source for use in apps

Tags: java, android, build, android-source, android-build

I want to make a little modification to the Android source to meet my requirement. Here is the requirement:

I want index all the objects in an Android app by adding one more public `int` field to the `java.lang.Object` class. Therefore, all the classes can inherit the newly added field because all of them are the subclasses of the `Object` class.

What I have done so far is modify the `java.lang.Object` class under `<Android_source>/libcore/libart/src/main/java/java/lang` folder and recompile the source.

I want to ask if I am doing the right thing. Can my Android app recognize this change (e.g. can a `String` object access the newly added field)?

**Edit**

After around 3 weeks try and error, I finally got the complete answer. I want to share this experience with others if anybody else want to modify the core java libraries of Android source (e.g., modifying `Object.java` and `String.java` etc.). Again, as mentioned by Michael, please note that such a modification may only be suitable for research or testing purpose.

The key challenge in making a successful modification (here 'successful' means the modified Android source can be built and run on emulators or real devices without any problem) is that some of the classes in the core java library have their C++ mirrors (located in `<Android_source>/art/runtime/mirrors/`). When modifying these java classes, you should also make the same modifications to their C++ mirrors. Otherwise, you could fail the build process because there are a bunch of checkings that you need to pass. Since I only add a new field to the `Object.java`, I will list some checkings (or requirements) I encountered below:

1.The size of an object instance = the size of its C++ mirror. For example, if I add a `long` field into `Object.java`, I should also add a `uint64_t` field to its C++ mirror to make their size equal.

2.Try to make the size of an object instance be the power of 2 (e.g., 2, 4, 8, 16, ...). For example, the size of the original `Object.java` is 8, therefore I add a long field to increase the size to 16. If I add an int field, the size becomes 12 and it can fail many checkings. I don't figure out the exact reason but I guess it has something to do with [memory alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719845/memory-alignment-in-c-c).

3.Try to put primitive-type fields after non-primitive-type fields and primitive-type fields should be ordered by size. This means you should put reference-type fields in the front, followed by 8-byte-primitive-type fields, then 4-byte-primitive-type fields, then 2-byte-primitive-type fields, then 1-byte-primitive-type fields. Again, I guess the reason is [memory alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719845/memory-alignment-in-c-c)

That's all I done to meet my requirements. I am open to any discussions if you have any ideas about the purpose of these checkings (especially the 2ed and 3rd one)

**New edit**

More specifically, I did the following things:

1. Add a new field (e.g., `public long tag;`) in `Object.java`
2. Change `static constexpr uint32_t kObjectHeaderSize = kUseBrooksReadBarrier ? 16 : 8;` to `static constexpr uint32_t kObjectHeaderSize = kUseBrooksReadBarrier ? 24 : 16;` in `Object.h`
3. Add the following method in `Object.h` (Only on Android 7)

```
static MemberOffset TagOffset() {
    return OFFSET_OF_OBJECT_MEMBER(Object, tag);
}
```

4. Add a new public field `public: uint64_t tag;` in `Object.h`
5. Change

```
#define MIRROR_OBJECT_CLASS_OFFSET 0
ADD_TEST_EQ(MIRROR_OBJECT_CLASS_OFFSET, art::mirror::Object::ClassOffset().Int32Value())
#define MIRROR_OBJECT_LOCK_WORD_OFFSET 4
ADD_TEST_EQ(MIRROR_OBJECT_LOCK_WORD_OFFSET, art::mirror::Object::MonitorOffset().Int32Value())
#if defined(USE_BROOKS_READ_BARRIER)
#define MIRROR_OBJECT_HEADER_SIZE 16
#else
#define MIRROR_OBJECT_HEADER_SIZE 8
```

to

```
#define MIRROR_OBJECT_CLASS_OFFSET 0
ADD_TEST_EQ(MIRROR_OBJECT_CLASS_OFFSET, art::mirror::Object::ClassOffset().Int32Value())
#define MIRROR_OBJECT_LOCK_WORD_OFFSET 4
ADD_TEST_EQ(MIRROR_OBJECT_LOCK_WORD_OFFSET, art::mirror::Object::MonitorOffset().Int32Value())
#define MIRROR_OBJECT_CLASS_TAG 8
ADD_TEST_EQ(MIRROR_OBJECT_CLASS_TAG, art::mirror::Object::TagOffset().Int32Value())

#if defined(USE_BROOKS_READ_BARRIER)
#define MIRROR_OBJECT_HEADER_SIZE 24
#else
#define MIRROR_OBJECT_HEADER_SIZE 16
```

in `asm_support.h` (Only on Android 7)

6. Add `addOffset(OFFSETOF_MEMBER(mirror::Object, tag), "tag");` in `class_linker_test.cc`
7. Change

```
static_assert(kObjectHeaderSize == sizeof(mirror::HeapReference<mirror::Class>) +
                    sizeof(LockWord),
```

to

```
static_assert(kObjectHeaderSize == sizeof(mirror::HeapReference<mirror::Class>) +
                    sizeof(LockWord) + 8,
```

in `art/runtime/gc/collector/concurrent_copying.cc`

8 Change `static constexpr size_t kFirstElementOffset = 12u;` to `static constexpr size_t kFirstElementOffset = 20u;` in `array.h`

9 Change `static constexpr size_t kObjectAlignmentShift = 3;` to `static constexpr size_t kObjectAlignmentShift = 4;` in `runtime_globals.h` (Not done yet)

10 Change

```
static_assert(kObjectAlignment == 8, "Alignment check");
class PACKED(8) ImageHeader {
```

to

```
static_assert(kObjectAlignment == 16, "Alignment check");
class PACKED(16) ImageHeader {
```

in `image.h` (Not done yet)

11 Change `static constexpr size_t kAlignment = 8;` to `static constexpr size_t kAlignment = 16;` in `gc::space::BumpPointerSpace` (Not done yet)

12 Change `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/local/bin/python` in `device/generic/goldfish/tools/mk_combined_img.py` (The value depends on your /bin/env python)(Only on Android 10)

13 Change

```
#define DCHECK_ALIGNED_PARAM(value, alignment) \
  DCHECK(::art::IsAlignedParam(value, alignment)) << reinterpret_cast<const void*>(value)
```

to

```
#define DCHECK_ALIGNED_PARAM(value, alignment) \
  DCHECK(::art::IsAlignedParam(value, alignment)) << reinterpret_cast<const void*>(value) << "," << alignment
```

in `art/libartbase/base/bit_utils.h` (for debug purpose)(Only for Android 11)

14 Change

```
DCHECK_ALIGNED_PARAM(remaining_space, object_class->GetObjectSize());
      Object* end = dst + remaining_space / object_class->GetObjectSize();
```

to

```
DCHECK_ALIGNED_PARAM(remaining_space, kObjectAlignment);
      Object* end = dst + remaining_space / kObjectAlignment;
```

in `art/dex2oat/linker/image_writer.cc` (Only for Android 11)

15. Change

```
memcpy(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(to_ref) + kObjectHeaderSize,
         reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(from_ref) + kObjectHeaderSize,
         obj_size - kObjectHeaderSize);
```

to

```
memcpy(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(to_ref) + kObjectHeaderSize - 8,
         reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(from_ref) + kObjectHeaderSize - 8,
         obj_size - kObjectHeaderSize + 8);
```

in `concurrent_copying.cc` (on Android 10)([reference](https://ppfocus.com/0/te40d47c1.html))

Comment: This seems like a very extreme way of going about things, and your app will only run on devices running your customised build of AOSP. Wouldn't it just be much easier to create an interface with an `int` method in your app, and apply it to all relevant classes? Or are you trying to change other Android SDK classes as well by means of inheritance?

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your reply! Yes, I want the change apply to EVERY classes, including the core Java library, Android SDK classes, and my application classes. I make this customized AOSP only for research purpose, therefore this is actually the simplest way I could figure out to meet my requirement.

Comment: You'd also need to create a custom Android SDK and import that into Android Studio, else your new methods won't show up in Android Studio and won't compile. This link should be a good place to start: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks again! So basically what I am trying is do is feasible right? Why not pose an answer and I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I'd like to state that I don't think this is a good idea and is probably overkill outside of research purposes. If you are modifying AOSP then the code you write will be dependent on the target device running that customised build of AOSP. However, it is still possible.

I'm assuming you already know how to compile and flash a custom AOSP build to a device. In order to write code that makes use of your new functionality, you'll also need to compile a custom SDK. This is so that Android Studio will know that your new method exists within `Object`, and can compile correctly against it. The full documentation can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt), but essentially it boils down to:

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch sdk-eng
make sdk
```

When you have your SDK zip file, you'll need to unzip it to your SDK's `platforms` directory - it should now show up checked in your SDK manager. If you have given your SDK a custom platform ID then you should be able to use that in your `build.gradle` files.

**Disclaimer:** This advice is purely from memory, it's a lengthy process so I've not had time to double-check, and chances are there may be a couple of minor things I've missed. This should get you most of the way towards where you want to be though.