# compiled with gcc6.2.0 & gcc8.3.0 will get difference alignment for local variable

Tags: c++, gcc

```
#include <iostream>
struct foo {
  char c[12];
};

int main()
{
  foo fa;
  foo fb;
  std::cout << &fa << "\n";
  std::cout << &fb << "\n";
}
```

With GCC 6.2, the output:
0x7fff67cd1ff0
0x7fff67cd1fe0
The difference is 16 bytes

With GCC 8.3, the output:
0x7ffc5fe3cf14
0x7ffc5fe3cf08
The difference is 12 bytes

It seems gcc6.2.0 has different default stack alignment with gcc8.3.0. And I also tried the -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4, but it seems not work.

I want to eliminate the difference between gcc6.2.0 and gcc8.3.0, can anyone tell me that if some options can disable that, thanks.

Comment: You may be pleased to know that as of GCC6.4 you get the offset of 12. Or maybe not so pleased since you're so close and yet so far.

Comment: Unrelated: Cheese hack to get more readable output: `std::cout << (char *)&fa - (char *)&fb << "\n";`. Total UB, but fun UB.

Comment: *I want to eliminate the difference between gcc6.2.0 and gcc8.3.* -- Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Why the importance in where the compiler places local variables?  There is no guarantee what the compiler does as long as the compiler follows the [as-if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rule.

Comment: Could it be the padding of the struct, instead of stack alignement ...  what does sizeof(fa) and sizeof(fb) tells you about their size ? You could pass the -Wpadded flag to check if gcc is padding the structs.

Comment: sizeof(fa) == sizeof(fb) == 12 for both gcc-6.2.0 and gcc-8.3.0.

if I add align attribute for both fa & fb, both gcc-6.2.0 and gcc-8.3.0 will give me the exact same result.
``` 
foo fa __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
 foo f6 __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
```

Comment: Looks like it was a bug in 6.2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59074271/why-are-all-arrays-aligned-to-16-bytes-on-my-implementation