# memory of a reference variable in c++?

Tags: c++

I've just started to learn Cpp from the basics and am confused when I came across reference variables.

From what I have learn't reference variables are just like an alias (another name to the same memory), so in this case it need need any memory.

When I ran the below code:

```
class sample_class
{
    public:
        int num; //line1
        int& refnum = num; //line2
}

int main()
{
    sample_class sample_object;
    cout<< "sample_class object size : " << sizeof(sample_object) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I got the output as:

> > sample_class object size : 8

==>Here, the size for `num` is 4 bytes (32-bit compiler) and `refnum` since a reference is simply an alias to `num`. Then, why in this case, the size of object is `8`?

==>Also, if really an `refnum` is like an alias then when does this information (info that `refnum` also holds/alias to the same memory address of `num`) gets stored?

***Edited :***

And consider this case (changine the definition of `sample_class`):

```
class sample_class
{
    public:
        char letter; //line3
        char& refletter = letter; //line4
        char letter_two; //line5
}
```

Here, If I print the object size of `sample_class` object, I get it as `12` (though the size of `letter`,`refletter` and `letter_two` are each equal to `1`). But if I comment `line 4`, the object size is just `2`. **How is this happening???**

***I'm interested to learn from the basics, so if I'm wrong anywhere please correct me***

Comment: Is the `i` in `int& refnum = i;` meant to be `num`?

Comment: sry... Its a typo mistake... edited...

Answer (score 8):

A reference is an alias, it should not be considered as a new variable. You cannot obtain its address and you cannot obtain its size. Any attempt to do so will instead obtain the address or size of the aliased object. In practice, most implementations implement them like pointers, but the standard does not require this. It makes no mention of the expected size for a reference.

From : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

> References are not objects; they do not necessarily occupy storage, although the compiler may allocate storage if it is necessary to implement the desired semantics (e.g. a non-static data member of reference type usually increases the size of the class by the amount necessary to store a memory address).

Edit : The c++ standard gives a lot of leeway to implementations to decide for themselves the size of types and classes in order to accommodate the unique requirements of every architecture. In this case, padding is introduced between the members of your class. There is no requirement in c++ that a class's size must be equal to the sum of it's members' size. See [Objects and alignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object) on cppreference.com for more information on the subject.

Edit 2 : There still seems to be some confusion regarding `sizeof(T&)`.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof :

> When applied to a reference type, the result is the size of the referenced type.

The expression `sizeof(T&)` is treated as if you had written `sizeof(T)`. This doesn't mean that the size of `T&` is equal to the size of `T`. It's simply that you cannot get the size of a reference directly with `sizeof`.

Comment: @saikiran That's a different question with a different answer, but Dr t's answer addresses the most likely possibility: padding to ensure optimal memory alignment.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer already provided I would recommend having a read of the material regarding padding at:

[Data structure padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025269/data-structure-padding)

Which is a good basic discussion regarding padding of classes and structures in C++ with simple examples to consider.

Comment: I have gone through the link @Dr t, but I'm using all `char` here, so why there is a need for padding for each of those variables which are `char` (look at my new code - line3,4,5) and If I comment `line4`, why I get it size of object as `2`

Comment: @saikiran You have `char`, `char&` and `char`. The memory layout requirements for a reference are not fixed by the standard, but they will likely be different from `char`'s. Compare with the size of a `struct` containing three `char` (no reference). Remember that `sizeof(T&)` gives the size of the type T, not the size of a reference. `sizeof(char&) == 1` *does not imply* that `char&` has a size of 1, only that `char` has a size of 1.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I observed what you said. But, even though `char&` is taking `1 byte`, why the compiler padded the remaining bytes?
In case of `int`, it is different but here why is it padding for the remaining normal `char` also?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, but in my case the value what `char&` is refering to  is also `1 byte` since the size of `letter` is `1 byte`

Comment: @saikiran `char&` does *not* take 1 byte. `sizeof(char&)` only measures the size of `char`. See the 2nd edit to my answer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah I got it now, but still I didn't get why the compiler padded so many bytes?

Comment: @saikiran You are likely on a x86 platform, where a reference has a size of 4 and has an alignment requirement of 4. Since your members are stored in order, you would have 1 byte for `letter`, 3 bytes of padding (since references may only begin on every 4th byte), 4 bytes for `refletter` and then 1 more byte for `letter_two`. I'm not sure what the last 3 bytes are used for, I would guess that the since the alignment requirement of your `struct` is 4, it's padded to a multiple of 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

A reference store the address of the variable it reference (like pointer with stronger pre/post-conditions).
<s>This means that `sizeof(T&) == sizeof(T*) == 4` on a 32bit architecture</s>.

Comment from @FrançoisAndrieux about the real size of `T&`:

> @nefas You state "This means that `sizeof(T&) == sizeof(T*) == 4` on a 32bit architecture." but this is not true. Try it with a larger `T`. For example, `sizeof(std::array<int, 10>&)` is much larger than a pointer. You are taking the size of `T`, not `T&`.

An other thing that you have to take into account when calculating size of class/struct is the padding of the struct/class: the size of the struct maybe higher than the sum of the size of its member (I won't explain how the padding work because I haven't enough knowledge about it).

Comment: Implementing references as pointers is no mandated by the standard, it's merely an overwhelmingly popular implementation choice.

Comment: That is on the implementation level, but not on the language level!

Comment: I did not say that one were implemented using the other but I said that they had similar semantic.

Comment: I did not knew, that. I've updated my answer to take into account your comment.