# How to fix static assert compile error C2338

Tags: c++

I have used a static assertion in this code:

```
struct XwaCraft
{
    char unk000[4];
    unsigned short CraftIndex;
    int LeaderObjectIndex;
    char unk00A[29];
    char SFoilsState;
    char unk028[568];
    unsigned char MeshRotationAngles[50];
    char unk292[359];
};

static_assert(sizeof(XwaCraft) == 1017, "size of XwaCraft must be 1017");

struct XwaMobileObject
{
    char unk00[221];
    XwaCraft* pCraft;
    char unkE1[4];
};

static_assert(sizeof(XwaMobileObject) == 229, "size of XwaMobileObject must be 229");

struct XwaObject
{
    char unk000[2];
    unsigned short ModelIndex;
    char unk004[1];
    unsigned char TieFlightGroupIndex;
    char unk006[25];
    int PlayerIndex;
    XwaMobileObject* pMobileObject;
};

static_assert(sizeof(XwaObject) == 39, "size of XwaObject must be 39");
```

for some strange reasons: I get these errors:

```
Error   C2338   size of XwaMobileObject must be 229
Error   C2338   size of size of XwaObject must be 39
```

The row: "size of XwaCraft must be 1017" is valid.

Is not clear why I get this error to only 2 rows and not 3.

Can you help me to fix it ?

Thanks !

Comment: `Can you help me to fix it ?` Well, change the number `229` to the size of the structure.

Comment: Your pointer is likely 8 bytes and not 4.

Comment: Your asserts are assuming 32-bit pointers and no padding (note that `XwaCraft` has no pointer members). Are you perhaps building a 64-bit target?

Comment: Don't forget about [structure padding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6025269/10871073)

Comment: Many thanks !! If I compile in 32 bit work !!

Comment: so, as said by molbdnilo, it's all about struct padding and pointers size: you have to adjust your asserts in order to consider the build architecture and the paddings