# googletest - memcmp failing on identical structs

Tags: c++, unit-testing, struct, googletest

I'm using `nanopb` (same as google protobuf) to generate structs.

```
TEST(MyTest, DataInfo_tSerDes)
{
    DataInfo_t DataInfo_t_data_to_ser = DataInfo_t_init_default;
    DataInfo_t DataInfo_t_data_from_ser = DataInfo_t_init_default;
    DataInfo_t DataInfo_t_default = DataInfo_t_init_default;

    int cmp_val2;
    cmp_val2 = memcmp(&DataInfo_t_data_to_ser, &DataInfo_t_data_from_ser, sizeof(DataInfo_t));
    // Make sure the input is different from the current output
    EXPECT_EQ(cmp_val2, 0);
}
```

Output:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from MyTest
[ RUN      ] MyTest.DataInfo_tSerDes
test_1.cpp:477: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  cmp_val2
    Which is: -51
  0
[  FAILED  ] MyTest.DataInfo_tSerDes(0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from MyTest (0 ms total)
```

My `EXPECT_EQ` statement is failing; why?

How can those two structs, initialized to same struct initialization value, not be the same?

Comment: You should be using `operator==`, not `memcmp()`, defining it if necessary. You don't know and cannot control what may be in the slack bytes.

Comment: The value `-51` is suggestive, in hex it's `0xCD`, which is the value MS compilers place in uninitialised memory.

Comment: Keyword: "padding".

Comment: Use `memcpy`, not `=` if you're going to use `memcmp`.

Comment: @user207421 unfortunately the `==` operator is not defined for structs so I'll fill in with zeros first and then initialize.

Comment: Pretty sure you would get similar problem with uninitialized memory without using gtest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data structure padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025269/data-structure-padding)

Comment: @Bob You can define your own `operator==` for any struct you like. But consistency is the key, use memcpy/memcmp or `=` and `==`

Comment: please post a [mcve]. Is `std::is_trivially_copyable_v<DataInfo_t>` `true` ?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt that's super interesting. They should look at the raw memory to confirm

Answer (score 3):

The struct might have a few so-called padding bytes between the fields. These bytes have no meaning, they are there because the other fields must be aligned to 2^n bytes. (E.g., `int`-s must be aligned to 4 bytes.)

e.g., `struct S { char c; int i; };` will have 3 padding bytes between `c` and `i` as if it were declared like this: `struct S { char c; char __padding[3]; int i; };`. These padding bytes are usually ignored by assignment and equality comparison, but `memcmp` (and `memcpy`, and other functions that operate at a byte -- and not at C++ object -- level) do see these bytes and are affected by it.

As mentioned in the comments, the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler fills these padding bytes with `0xCD` values.